# Ubuntu BIND in LAN problems - DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds

Tags: 14.04, networking, bind

I've got a BIND9 setup on my local network via Webmin. A nslookup doesn't seem to work. Neither does ping google.de. Been looking around and trying several different settings. Nothing has worked so far.

---

From a Windows machine:

```
C:\Users\copys_000>nslookup - 192.168.178.120
Default Server:  copystring.intranet
Address:  192.168.178.120

> google.de
Server:  copystring.intranet
Address:  192.168.178.120

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to copystring.intranet timed-out
```

---

From the Ubuntu running the BIND9 server:

```
root@Asus-PC:/home/copystring# nslookup - 192.168.178.120
> google.de
Server:         192.168.178.120
Address:        192.168.178.120#53

** server can't find google.de: SERVFAIL
```

---

`cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        195.50.140.118;
        195.50.140.180;
        };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

---

`cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

# Our forward zone

# Our reverse Zone
# Server IP 192.168.178.120

zone "netflix.com" {
        type forward;
        forwarders {
                208.122.23.23;
                208.122.232.22;
                };
        };
zone "copystring.intranet" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/copystring.intranet.hosts";
        notify yes;
        allow-query { any; };
        };
zone "178.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/192.168.178.rev";
        notify yes;
        allow-query { any; };
        };
```

`cat /var/lib/bind/192.168.178.rev`:

```
$ttl 38400
178.168.192.in-addr.arpa.       IN      SOA     Asus-PC. copystring.gmail.com. (
                        1410892685
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
178.168.192.in-addr.arpa.       IN      NS      Asus-PC.
120.178.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR     copystring.intranet.
```

---

`cat /var/lib/bind/copystring.intranet.hosts`:

```
$ttl 38400
copystring.intranet.    IN      SOA     Asus-PC. copystring.gmail.com. (
                        1410892662
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
copystring.intranet.    IN      NS      Asus-PC.
copystring.intranet.    IN      A       192.168.178.120
copystring.intranet.    IN      MX      10 copystring.intranet
```

Comment: Found a solution here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

I've had to add these lines to /etc/bind/named.conf.options:

forward only;

dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation yes;